# TypeError: structural_similarity() takes 2 positional arguments but 8 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

When I calculate the similarity between two grayscale images in python and opencv, the function called `compare_ssim()` is reported incorrectly.

```py
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(gray1, gray2, full=True)
```

The error message is as follows:

> TypeError: structural_similarity() takes 2 positional arguments but 8 were given

This is a function from library. From the `_structural_similarity.py` file.The directory is `\skimage\measure\_structural_similarity.py`.

```py
def compare_ssim(X, Y, win_size=None, gradient=False,
                 data_range=None, multichannel=False, gaussian_weights=False,
                 full=False, **kwargs):
    warn('DEPRECATED: skimage.measure.compare_ssim has been moved to '
         'skimage.metrics.structural_similarity. It will be removed from '
         'skimage.measure in version 0.18.', stacklevel=2)
       return structural_similarity(X, Y, win_size, gradient,
                                 data_range, multichannel, gaussian_weights, 
                                 full, **kwargs)
```

> `return` line, error message is displayed in this line.

And `structural_similarity()`.The directory of this function is `\skimage\metrics\_structural_similarity.py`, the function is as follows:

```py
def structural_similarity(im1, im2,
                          *,
                          win_size=None, gradient=False, data_range=None,
                          multichannel=False, gaussian_weights=False,
                          full=False, **kwargs):
```

What is the problem, why is this?

Comment: Hi Frans Fan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to give the full traceback of the exception you're getting, rather than only the final message. It's mentioning a function you're not calling directly, so it's not obvious where things are going wrong. I've also added a few tags to your question, so while editing, double check I got them right (and add any more than are appropriate). Is `compare_ssim` a function you wrote? If so, include its code too! If it's from a library, please say where it's from.

Comment: I don't see a `structural_similarity` function in the opencv library. Do you know where this function comes from? You mention a `structural_similarity` *file*, where does that come from? Also, is there a definition of the `structural_similarity` function somewhere (i.e., `def structural_similarity(....):`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
```

Do try...

Comment: instead of this "compare_ssim"

Answer (score 2):

I tried using this :

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
...
s = ssim(gray_image_1,gray_image_2)
```

here, gray_image_1.shape = gray_image_2.shape = (420,420).
This worked for me (python 3.6.6).

`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your patience. I have solved this problem.
It should be a function call error.when I replace the header file 'from skimage.measures import compare_ssim'  with `from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity`, and replace the function call with a `(score, diff) = structural_similarity(gray1, gray2, full=True)`, compiled successfully